# Update only first row content while selecting data from table in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have below sample table

```
create table employee 
(
    id int primary key,
    name varchar(50),
    department varchar(10),
)

insert into employee 
values (2, 'John', 'HR'),
       (5, 'Michael', 'IT'),
       (28, 'Rakesh', 'TP'),
       (49, 'Xi', 'IT')
```

While selecting all rows from the above table, I would like to get ID value of first row in my output as 0. So the response of the query shown should be like this:

```
select * 
from employee
where department  = 'IT'

id   name      department
-------------------------
0    Michael   IT
49   Xi        IT
```

Value of `ID` column should always be 0 in only FIRST row. I was able to achieve it using a temp table. I store output of query into a temp table and then run an update query like below

```
update #temp 
set id = 0 
where id = (select min(id) from #temp)
```

I am wondering if there is any simpler way to achieve it by just using select queries and not by inserting data to a temp table.

Comment: As far as the database is concerned, there is _no such thing_ as a first row. Rows can re-ordered on disk, or returned in other than disk order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use `first_value` windowing function here:

```
select 
  case 
    when id = First_Value(id) over (order by id) 
    then 0 else id 
  end Id,
  name, department
from dbo.employee
where department = 'IT';
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest the following.

```sql
select case row_number() over (order by id)
         when 1 then 0
         else id
       end as id
      ,name
      ,department
  from employee
 where department = 'IT'
```

Results of above query (using sample data from your question):

| id | name | department |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Michael | IT |
| 49 | Xi | IT |

Refer to this [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/VothjiJn).
Also refer to documentation for [ROW_NUMBER](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) and [CASE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16).